# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008 Reporting Server - WMI Error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a copy of SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2014 on my machine.

Reporting services has been installed and configured for both instances

- SQL Server 2008 instance - `machinename\SQL08`
- SQL Server 2014 instance - `machinename`

However I can't connect to the 2008 instance of the report server.

From SSMS 2014 I see the following

[image: SSMS 2014]

From SSMS 2008 I see the following

[image: SSMS 2008]

From the Reporting Server Configuration for 2014 I get the following, which shows that it can connect to the 2014 report server

[image: Report Server Configuration 2014]

From the Reporting Server Configuration for 2008 I get the following, which shows that it isn't able to see any servers

[image: Report Server Configuration 2008]

When I enter the 08 reporting instance I get the following error message.

[image: 2008 Error]

Has anyone seen this WMI error message and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure the reporting service is actually running? From the run command type "Services.msc" and search for SQL Server Reporting Services. It should be running and set to "Automatic"

If its running and issue still persist then please check your firewall.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes the service is running. I'm running all this locally, so I'm not going through the firewall.